# Highlight text in editor window (Texstudio)

Tags: texstudio, editors, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to highlight some text in the editor window (like WinEdt does). For example, by typing:

> \textbf{some text}

I would like to have the phrase "some text" in bold in the editor window, that is:

> \textbf{**some text**}

Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: Nothing I know about and I can't find anything alike in the options. Please do a feature request here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/ if you need this. You should be clear on what cases you want to see. Italic, bold, emphasised... nested forms, math forms. Consider providing an MWE which shows all the cases you know and need. You might want to show some reference on how this is treated in WinEdt (in case this is open content, I do not know this editor).